# telegram bot answers not as he should

Tags: python, bots

So, i have created a telegram bot for my school homework, and i decided to make a movie bot which recommend you some movies to watch. By the plan it should answer on "Comedy" or "Horror" or "Drama" with top 5 movies. And if i or any other user writes something that bot doesn't know, then he has to respond "I did not understand you..." But in fact he answers with "I did not understand you" on everything i send him. I tried everything, nothing works. Help please

```
from typing import Final
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, ContextTypes

TOKEN: Final = '
BOT_USERNAME: Final = 'movieinight_bot'


# Commands

async def start_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.message.reply_text(
        'Hello! Looking for watching anything tonight? Send me the wished category and '
        'i will send you some of films in my collection!')


async def help_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.message.reply_text(
        'Hello! I am a Movie Night Bot, I will help you choose which film to '
        'watch this night! To make your experience better, '
        'i ask you, to write a request in a following format "Genre" or "I want to watch Genre"')


# Responses


def handle_response(text: str):
    processed: str = text.lower()

    if 'Comedy' in processed:
        return 'Super choice! Here are top 5 films: "Blazing Saddles"; ‘Airplane!’; ‘Monty Python and the Holy Grail’; ' \
               '‘Monty Python and the Holy Grail’; ‘Animal House’;  ‘Young Frankenstein’ '

    if 'Horror' in processed:
        return 'Wow! Love watching horrors? Here are some of Horror Movies from my collection: ' \
               'The Exorcist (1973); Halloween (1978); Paranormal Activity ' \
               '(2007); The Shining (1980); It Follows (2014) '

    if 'Drama' in processed:
        return 'Nice choice! Here are some of Drama films I have: Citizen Kane (1941); The Godfather ' \
               '(1972); 12 Angry Men (1957); Casablanca (1942); Tokyo Story (1953) '

    return 'I did not understand...'


async def handle_message(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    message_type: str = update.message.chat.type
    text: str = update.message.text

    print(f'User ({update.message.chat.id}) in {message_type}: "{text}"')

    # Check if the message is a command, and if so, don't process the response
    if text.startswith('/'):
        return

    if message_type == 'group':
        if BOT_USERNAME in text:
            new_text: str = text.replace(BOT_USERNAME, '').strip()
            response: str = handle_response(new_text)
        else:
            return
    else:
        response: str = handle_response(text)

    print('Bot:', response)
    await update.message.reply_text(response)


async def error(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    print(f'Update {update} caused error {context.error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Starting bot...')
    app = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()

    # Commands
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_command))
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('help', help_command))

    # Messages
    app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, handle_message))

    # Errors
    app.add_error_handler(error)

    # Polls the bot
    print('Polling...')
    app.run_polling(poll_interval=3)
```

I tried to shorten a bit bot answers, did not help. Re-watched tutorial many times, still don't understand what i did wrong.

Comment: You use `processed: str = text.lower()` and then you check if "Comedy" (or any other type) with capital letter is in the text - this will always be false. Use "comedy" instead.

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Looks like it's time to debug. Put a break point at the first 'if' of handle_response and check the value of 'text'.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely all groups are automatically converted into supergroup (I created a group, added a bot there (during creation) and it became supergroup)

So the problem might be in this line `if message_type == 'group':`. Replace it with `if message_type == 'group' or message_type == 'supergroup':`

Also don't forget what @TDG mentioned in the comments:

> You use processed: str = `text.lower()` and then you check if "Comedy"
> (or any other type) with capital letter is in the text - this will
> always be false. Use "comedy" instead.

And I would recommend using the [filters](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions---Advanced-Filters) to send messages of certain types (and/or which contain some text) to a specific handler.

Comment: Thank you so much @elebur and @TDG! It started working!